# Calculate the amount of the series $\sum_{n=0}^{‎\infty‎}‎\frac{\pi^n n^2}{n!2^{n}}‎|z|^n$.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

According to my research, I need to calculate the amount of the following series. So, Wolfram Alpha helps me to obtain the answer as follows.
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=0}^{‎\infty‎}‎\frac{\pi^n n^2}{n!2^{n}}‎|z|^n=‎\frac{1}{4}\pi ‎e^{‎\frac{\pi|z|}{2}‎}|z|(\pi|z|+2)
\end{align*}

**'Now my question is:** How we can arrive at the answer (what is the method)?

Also, I know that $\sum_{n=0}^{‎\infty‎}‎\frac{\pi^n }{n!2^{n}}‎|z|^n=‎e^{‎\frac{\pi|z|}{2}‎}$, but I could not achieve the result.

Comment: Hint: Differentiate with respect to $z$.

Answer (score 5):

\begin{align}
f(z):=\sum_{n=0}^{‎\infty‎}‎\frac{n^2}{n!}‎z^n&=\sum_{n=1}^{‎\infty‎}‎\frac{n}{(n-1)!}‎z^n\\
&=z\sum_{n=0}^{‎\infty‎}‎\frac{n+1}{n!}‎z^n\\
&=ze^z+z\sum_{n=0}^{‎\infty‎}‎\frac{n}{n!}‎z^n\\
&=ze^z+z\sum_{n=1}^{‎\infty‎}‎\frac{1}{(n-1)!}‎z^n\\
&=(z+z^2)e^z.\\
\end{align}
Your function is simply $f(\frac\pi2|z|)$.

P.S. Also see [Touchard polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touchard_polynomials).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, in the second equality from the bottom, is the series true?

Comment: @soodehMehboodi the second to last equality is just cancelling out the $n$s and ignoring $n=0$, since the term is $0$ there

Answer (score 3):

Let us set $x=\frac\pi2|z|$. Since $n^2=n(n-1) + n$, we get
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
\sum_{n=0}^{‎\infty‎}‎\frac{\pi^n n^2}{n!2^{n}}‎|z|^n
& = &
\sum_{n=0}^{‎\infty‎}‎\frac{n^2}{n!}‎x^n \\
& = &
\sum_{n=0}^{‎\infty‎}‎\frac{n(n-1)}{n!}‎x^n
+
\sum_{n=0}^{‎\infty‎}‎\frac{n}{n!}‎x^n\\
& = &
\sum_{n=2}^{‎\infty‎}‎\frac{n(n-1)}{n!}‎x^n
+
\sum_{n=1}^{‎\infty‎}‎\frac{n}{n!}‎x^n
\\
& = &
\sum_{n=0}^{‎\infty‎}‎\frac1{n!}‎x^{n+2}
+
\sum_{n=0}^{‎\infty‎}‎\frac1{n!}‎x^{n+1} \\
& = &
(x^2+x)e^x\\
& = &
(\frac{\pi^2}4|z|^2+\frac{\pi}2|z|)e^{\frac\pi2|z|}\\
& = &
\frac{1}{4}\pi ‎e^{‎\frac{\pi|z|}{2}‎}|z|(\pi|z|+2)
\end{array}
$$